# How to calculate $P(X<Y)$ of two random variables

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions

I want to calculate the following probability of two random variables (we don't know if they are independant) $P(X<Y)$.

In the case they are discrete it is easy: $P(X<Y)=\sum_{-k=\infty}^{+\infty}P(X < Y \cap Y=k)=\sum_{-k=\infty}^{+\infty}\sum_{j=-\infty }^kP(X=j\cap Y=k)$

The question is the following: What is $P(X<Y)$ in the case of $X,Y$ being continuous ? The intuitive answer would be to replace $P(X=j\cap Y=k)$ with the joint density function $f_{X,Y}$ and so to have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{y}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$

Is this correct or is there a mistake somewhere?

Comment: "Is this correct" Quite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ have joint density $f(x,y)$, then for any Borel subset $D\subset{\bf R}^2$, one has
$$
P((X,Y)\in D) = \iint_{D}f(x,y)\,dxdy.
$$

In your example, you have $D = \{(x,y)\in{\bf R}^2\mid x<y\}$. By the Fubini theorem, 
$$
P(X<Y) = \iint_{\{x<y\}}f(x,y)\,dxdy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^yf(x,y)\,dxdy.
$$

So the integral you have is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to apply the law of total probability :

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X<Y) &= \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{P}(X<Y \mid Y = y) f_Y(y) dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)f_Y(y) dx dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^y f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx dy\\
\end{align*}

Another way of doing that is using expectation :

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X<Y) &= \mathbb{E} [ \mathbb{1} (X<Y) ]\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{1} (x<y) f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^{y} f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx dy\\
\end{align*}

I prefer the second one since it matches better with measure theory.

Comment: To pass by conditional densities to reach absolute densities is unnecessary (and rather illogical, I must say). // And in the second part, aren't you simply repeating a part of the question?

Comment: @Did Could you expend on why it is illogical ? I don't really see your point. For second part it depends on how you define your random variable, but if you do it using the measure $f_{X,Y}$ then your done in one step since the expectation is defined as the Lebesgue integral of the argument. In the end is the Riemann integral I gave since the random variables are continuous.

Comment: Yes the second approach is the one -- unfortunately it is already explained in the question. The first one is illogical because $f_{X\mid Y}(x,y)$ is defined as the ratio $f_{X,Y}(x,y)/f_Y(y)$ hence to rediscover that the product $f_{X\mid Y}(x,y)f_Y(y)$ is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, is... well, going backwards.

Comment: Actually, it seems that the first reflex of many users on this site, when asked any question involving a joint distribution, is to rush to a conditional distribution, as if these were the primary notion in this context instead of the joint distributions themselves (from which one can in a second phase, yes, deduce conditional distributions). One day, I should find the courage (and the time) to study in depth the curricula based on this ill-conceived notion, to understand where it is coming from...

Comment: This is true, I understand what you mean.